# Tfs 2010: Why is my build account explicitly denied all permissions?

Tags: version-control, msbuild, tfsbuild

I'm setting up a new deployment of tfs 2010. I've got a couple stub projects to be built sitting inside a solution, and I'm attempting to configure a continuous integration build on it. So, I configured a build with all the defaults, and kicked it off. I got this error:

`TF215097: An error occurred while initializing a build for build definition \Ticm\Ticm.CI: Item $/Ticm/BuildProcessTemplates/DefaultTemplate.xaml was not found in source control at version T.`

I was sort of confused, because it sitting was right there in source control. Thinking for some reason it might be going off of my workspace (and because I think it's good practice to bind build templates to the branch they're building anyway) I moved BuildProcessTemplates inside my main branch, and created a custom CI build template in an adjacent folder.

`TF215097: An error occurred while initializing a build for build definition \Ticm\Ticm.CI: Item $/Ticm/main/build/templates/customBuilds/Ticm.CI.xaml was not found in source control at version T.`

Which is essentially the same thing.

In the build definition, I left the Build Agent Folder in "Working folders" as the default "$(SourceDir)". Does this need to be explicitly set or anything?
Anyone seen this before? Any idea where to look next?

**Edit:** After some more investigation, it seems that my TfsBuild account has been explicitly denied every single permission for this project. I don't really know how this happened. I used the build account for the user in Lab Management however (it described using a build and test service) so perhaps it was added in there so that the lab can't mess up source control or something?

I'd like to hear from anyone using Lab Management in tfs 2010 to see if their service account is also denied all these permissions; perhaps I just need to make another domain account and use that one instead.

Comment: Same here. Really strange! What have you done? chosen another build account or is there a way to remove all the explicit right settings quickly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that I misread the configuration information for Lab Management. When supplying the service account, the information reads "This service account will be used by test and build agents..." However reading the information posted [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd692846.aspx) it seems that trusted accounts such as build accounts, test accounts are explicitly not to be used. Perhaps because things like my problem can result!

Ha. Moral of the story: RTFM more closely.